# Two side by side images of same height with keyfloat

Tags: floats, keyfloat

I recently discovered the excellent keyfloat package, which allows great versatility in images arrangement, but I'm not able to obtain an apparently simple result, resize two side by side figures to the same height. In the following MWE I tried different kind of resizing (by linewidth, by scale, by height) but the result is not satisfactory at all:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}% without small font option results are worse
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{keyfloat}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{yellow!12}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2} 

\section*{Introduction}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\begin{keyfloats}[H]{2}
\keyfig{lw=1,c={Side by side figures, left.}}{example-image-a}
\keyfig{lw=1,c={Side by side figures, right.}}{example-image-10x16}
\vspace{1ex}
\end{keyfloats}

\lipsum[3][1-11]

\begin{keyfloats}[H]{2}
\keyfig{lw=1.4,c={Side by side figures, left.}}{example-image-a}
\keyfig{lw=0.66,c={Side by side figures, right.}}{example-image-10x16}
\vspace{1ex}
\end{keyfloats}

\lipsum[3][1-11]

\begin{keyfloats}[H]{2}
\keyfig{s=0.32,c={Side by side figures, left.}}{example-image-a}
\keyfig{s=0.23,c={Side by side figures, right.}}{example-image-10x16}
\vspace{1ex}
\end{keyfloats}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\begin{keyfloats}[H]{2}
\keyfig{h=7.6em,c={Side by side figures, left.}}{example-image-a}
\keyfig{h=7.6em,c={Side by side figures, right.}}{example-image-10x16}
\vspace{1ex}
\end{keyfloats}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As visible, the problem consists in the fact that there is a gap on the right of the rightmost image.

Is it possible to fix such behavior or it is a feature/limitation of keyfloat package?

Moreover, if the `font=small` option of the `caption` package is not enabled, results are even worse.

Comment: interesting package but it does not seem to be used much. Maybe can you contact the author?

Comment: I did contact the author, hope this glitch can be solved cause the package looks really promising.

Comment: did you get an answer on this ?

Comment: The author made a new version soon after this question with some very nice improvements, but I did not investigate if this specific need was addressed. You might want to check yourself at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/keyfloat and report the answer here.

Comment: Am currently testing the package and it's the Swiss knife of floats. If I get an answer i' my process I'll post it here.